# Wikipedia Categories Starting with "Category:Lists_of_" returns just lists no data

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I wanted to extract all cities within the United States, so I ran this query.

```
SELECT ?s 
 WHERE {
  ?s dcterms:subject/skos:broader*  category:Lists_of_cities_in_the_United_States.

 }
```

But the results is [SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20%3Fs%20%0D%0A%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fs%20dcterms%3Asubject%2Fskos%3Abroader*%20%20category%3ALists_of_cities_in_the_United_States.%0D%0A%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on) which includes just lists and no data.
I also noticed some wikipedia pages that start with **"List_of"** but no "**Category:**" in front of them,  For example [List_of_cities_in_Canada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_in_Canada) how do extract them?

Comment: List_of_cities_in_Canada isn't a category;  it's an *article* (containing a list of cities in Canada).  It's in the *category* category:Lists_of_cities_in_Canada since, after all, a list of cities in Canada certainly belongs to the topic about lists of cities in Canada.  There are other lists of cities in Canada though, too, e.g.: dbpedia:List_of_towns_in_Quebec and dbpedia:List_of_largest_Canadian_cities_by_census.

Comment: That said, there have been some issues with skos:broader and property chains.  You might just want to specify a maximum depth rather than arbitrary recursion.  E.g., `skos:broader{,7}`.